# jQuery: Prevent enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress, forms

I am trying to prevent the <kbd>enter</kbd> key from being put into a textarea, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$('#comment').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.text.charCodeAt() == '10') {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: I dont think the event is triggering, how can I tell if `$('#comment')` is correctly being what I want?

Comment: Rememebr to hook into the change event as well as the keyup/down/press that everybody else has displayed. with every solution here, people can still paste linebreaks into th textarea, to prevent that you need to remove them ;)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I have written little demonstration on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/EmfAn/1/), where you can try this code

Everybody has right answer :)

```
$('#comment').keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 10 || event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Bubby LOL accepted answer for copy-pasting someone else's code into jsfiddle?

Comment: Just as a note; keyCode 10 is needed because Safari on iPhones sends keycode 10 when enter is pressed

Comment: @Ben When I tested it sends 13 instead of 10. Is there any document about that? I cannot find one.

Comment: @Sangdol there should be some documentation on standard keycodes; but 10 and 13 are both needed, hence the OR operator

Comment: Instead of `keyCode` you can just use `which`.

Answer (score 16):

You can't cancel a `keyup` event. You can cancel `keydown` and `keypress` events though.  In the documentation, notice that under "Event Information", "Cancels" is "No" for `keyup`:

- [keyup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536940(VS.85).aspx)
- [keydown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536938(VS.85).aspx)
- [keypress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536939(VS.85).aspx)

Using `keydown` allows you to cancel far more keys than `keypress`, but if you don't want to cancel until after the key has been lifted, `keypress` is what you want.  Fortunately for you, the enter key is one of the cancellable keys for the `keypress` event.

Answer (score 8):

Use `event.keyCode` in the `keydown` event:

```
$('#comment').keydown(function(event) {
   if(event.keyCode == 13) return false;
   //carry on...
});
```

Comment: @Šime Vidas I guess you could use the `keydown` event.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#comment').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Wha? The keycode for the Enter key is `13`, not `10`.

Comment: 10 is LF (line feed) and 13 is CR (carriage return). He should prevent both.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski: No. The keyCode is **always** 13. See e.g. http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 3):

While the answers provided here will prevent someone from typing a carriage return, it will not prevent someone from pasting one in.

You would need to do some post processing of the text (in javascript or server-side) to remove them.

http://jsfiddle.net/we8Gm/

**But the question is, why?**  Why not simply use `<input type="text"></input>` which takes care of this automatically as it is a single-line input element?

Comment: Because I need the box to be tall, not wide. There's only like 50 px of width.

Comment: Now I am curious what you would use a tall skinny input for.

Comment: Ajax chat widget I designed, so a user can hit enter to submit the message.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `.keypress` and use `return false`;

Good luck!