# Is there any way to prevent enter event on jquery datepicker

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a textbox which opens jquery datepicker calender when I press enter inside it.
Is there any way to prevent opening the calender on enter press?

Comment: Q&A's here may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753823/jquery-prevent-enter-key (after Googling "jQuery prevent enter") ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help but i dont want to completely prevent the enter. I want to call an ajax function on enter press rather than opening the calendar.

Comment: do you have any sample code to start with?  by default the calender opens when it gets focus, hitting enter selects the date

Comment: I have just used `$('.shipdate').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
        });`

Comment: after you get your ajax response what are you doing?

Comment: do you want to only capture the enter event or when the calender is about to display regardless

Comment: i am inserting the date in my database. Actually for my ajax to get run i need to press enter twice as on first enter the calendar gets open. And I want my ajax to run on first enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments I am convinced there is a better user experience than double tap enter.

Perhaps when a date is selected you could call ajax?  There are other options as well that all just utilize the datapicker event callbacks.

```
  $( ".shipdate" ).datepicker(
      {
          onSelect: function(input, obj) {
              //callajax, where input is the date
          }
      }
  );
```