# How to disable enter key inside jqueryui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQueryUI date picker and when user clicks on a textbox and hits the enter key the current date gets populated. I want to avoid that. I have tried this:

```
$('#datepicker').on('keypress',  function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false; 
    }
});
```

With no luck

here is the link of demo https://jsfiddle.net/shalini456/zwjzo175/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable enter key in JQuery ui datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808416/disable-enter-key-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Prevent enter key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753823/jquery-prevent-enter-key)

Comment: @CharlyH before posting my question i did try the solutions mentioned in SO but it doesnt work see https://jsfiddle.net/shalini456/zwjzo175/2/

Comment: @MaximeSavard the solution mentioned in that thread doesnt work for me :(

Comment: @Shalini look at my answer or at the solution from Bhupesh Kushwaha in the comments

Comment: @Shalini this does not make sense to me. In the docs, I see: *`ENTER`: Select the focused date.* Are users not focusing or selecting a date before they hit enter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#datepicker").keydown(myfunction); // use keydown

function myfunction(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no need for strict comparison here, or am I missing something?

Comment: can you provide the version of jQueryUI datepicker

Comment: @BhupeshKushwaha it doesnt work can you please try to edit and update https://jsfiddle.net/shalini456/zwjzo175/3/

Comment: hello try its work   <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input")
.bind('keydown', function (event) { 
if (event.which == 13) {
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 9;
e.keyCode = 9;
$(this).trigger(e);
return false;
}
}).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' }); 
});
</script>

Comment: @BhupeshKushwaha This works for me, you should update your answer. but I've made it shorter. Look at this fiddle : jsfiddle.net/zwjzo175/27

Answer (score 3):

Some of the solutions here *appear* to work because they throw an exception of some kind.

There are two things which seem to make it work without throwing an exception.

As mentioned by "Charly H" the keydown binding must happen before calling datepicker.

Then in the keydown handler call `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`. E.g.

```
  $('#datepicker').bind('keydown',function(e){

    if (e.which == 13)
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  })
  .datepicker();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8fyvh8wd/18/

Comment: This answer is the hero that Gotham deserves.

Comment: Binding keydown event handler before initializing the datepicker worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#datepicker').keypress(function(e){

    if (e.keyCode == 10 || e.keyCode == 13) //10 is Line Feed and 13 is Carriage Return
        e.preventDefault();

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant disable the enter keypress there is a work around for this... you can just remove the focus from `"#datepicker"` check the following updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shalini456/zwjzo175/4/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

  $("#datepicker").on('click', function(){
   $("#datepicker").blur();
  });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've shortened down the solution of Bhupesh Kushwaha, which he provided in the comments

```
$(function() {
    $("input").bind('keydown', function (e) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
    $(this).trigger(e); 
    return false; 
  } 
    }).datepicker(); 
  });
```

This worked for me: https://jsfiddle.net/zwjzo175/27/

Comment: This does not work. There is an error in the code (event is not defined). If I replace "event" by "e", it says "too much recursion".

Answer (score 0):

guys,

I know that this might be too late, but the only solution that worked for me was the one from "Charly H", where he put the code binding the input text before the declaration of the datepicker.

I guess the reason is that the bubble propagation and the priority of it.

The code would look like this:

```js
$(function() {
    $("input").bind('keydown', function (e) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).trigger(e); 
            return false;
        } 
    }).datepicker(); 
});
```

Comment: Calling `$(this).trigger(e);` is recursive, and throws a stack overflow exception, that's why it *sort of* works