# How to disable enter key on contenteditable? [on dynamically added elements]

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I want to disable enter key when i use `contenteditable="true"`
How can i make it?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cwjm5d4k/10/)

This code below doesnt work.

```
<p contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

.

```
$('p[contenteditable]').keyup(function(e) {
  return e.which !== 13 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/e73uv17L/3/)

```
$("p[contenteditable]").keypress(function (evt) {

  var keycode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
  if (keycode  == 13) { //Enter key's keycode
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: By the way, it seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753823/jquery-prevent-enter-key

Comment: Did you test this solution with dynamic elements ?

Comment: Yea i tested but not working  -> https://jsfiddle.net/cwjm5d4k/10/ Can you take a look ?

Comment: It's because you use a textarea here :https://jsfiddle.net/cwjm5d4k/12/

Comment: Textarea? I mean p element which is dynamically adding

Comment: Oh ok my bad. But it actually works in your example ..

Comment: Man i not working on me ??

Comment: When i press enter in your contenteditable p, it doesn't do a line break so it works. What does not work for you ?

Comment: Man it makes on me a line break , i dont get why

Comment: I know what you mean now. I made it works with a reload(), I don't know other way to do it. See here : https://jsfiddle.net/cwjm5d4k/18/

Comment: why jquery??????????? pure js